# Populating the Column dependent on the value of other columns SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to MYSQL. I have two columns A and B and I want to fill the column `C` such that value `(C) = func(valA, valB)`. I already have `A` and `B` columns filled and I want to make entries into column `C`. 
Any Help is appreciated. 
Thanks.
EDIT:

```
DECLARE @g geometry; 
SET @g = geometry::Point(Latitude, Longitude, 4326)
```

I need to insert @g in Column C and I have Latitude (Column A) and Longitude (Column B).
I am able to perform following operation:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET `C` = `A` + `B`
```

But when I am trying to perform

```
UPDATE myTable
SET `C` = geometry::Point(`A`, `B`, 4326), //--it gives me an error that `error occurred during execution of geometry`
```

Any Suggestions ? I am new to this, so I might be doing lot of things wrong.

Comment: You need to decide `MySQL` or `T-SQL`(SQL Server 2008R2). Also not clear, you need `UPDATE` column `C` or `SELECT`?

Comment: Do you really need a 3rd column with derived only data in it?

Comment: I need derived data in 3rd column from two columns and I am using SQL server 2008 R2. I would prefer to use MySQL as I don't have much idea of T-SQL

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
update your_table set C = Concat(A,',',B)
```

**EDIT:**

maybe you mean geography not geometry.

`GEOGRAPHY` is for coordinates/points and `GEOMETRY` is for regions/polygons.

try this

```
UPDATE myTable
SET `C` = geography::Point(`A`, `B`, 4326);
```

here some [Different ways to add point data in SQL Server 2008](http://colinmackay.co.uk/2008/02/07/different-ways-to-add-point-data-in-sql-server-2008/)